# Installation of Agiletoolkit where do I set mysql password for database test?

Tags: mysql, atk4

I am trying out agiletoolkit.  I get an error when I try to do the Database test.

```
PDO error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
DSN: mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example;charset=utf8
```

and then there is a traceback that does not really copy so well (It's at the end of this post)

**BACKGROUND**

I have WAMP installed on my windows 7 machine.  I have set a root password for mysql and I have also set that in phpmyadmin3.5.1\config.inc.php  so Phpmyadmin works and I can create tables and so on in phpmyadmin.

I have copied the agiletoolkit into my `www` directory.  It shows up as a hyperlink on the front page that WAMP creates.  All good.  When I click on that I get the agile toolkit I get the "Hello World from your own copy of Agile Toolkit" message -> all good so far.

At the top right of the page are some buttons - Welcome, Examples ... database test....
When I click on "database test", I get the error message shown above.

I assume that somewhere I need to tell agiletoolkit my mysql root password.

But where do I do that or do I do something else.

Thanks in advance

---

This is the error in full

```
http://localhost/agiletoolkit/?page=dbtest
```

BaseException

Database Connection Failed

Additional information:

```
PDO error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
DSN: mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example;charset=utf8

C:\wamp\www\agiletoolkit\atk4\lib\BaseException.php:38
```

Stack trace:

```
C:\wamp\www\agiletoolkit\atk4\lib/BaseException.php :38     BaseException   BaseException->collectBasicData(Null, 1, 0)
C:\wamp\www\agiletoolkit\atk4\lib/AbstractObject.php    :292    BaseException   BaseException->__construct("Database Connection Failed")
C:\wamp\www\agiletoolkit\atk4\lib/DB.php    :67     sample_project_db   DB->exception("Database Connection Failed")
C:\wamp\www\agiletoolkit\atk4\lib/ApiCLI.php    :329    sample_project_db   DB->connect(Null)
C:\wamp\www\agiletoolkit\page/dbtest.php    :7  sample_project  Frontend->dbConnect()
C:\wamp\www\agiletoolkit\atk4\lib/AbstractObject.php    :189    sample_project_dbtest   page_dbtest->init()
C:\wamp\www\agiletoolkit\atk4\lib/ApiFrontend.php   :92     sample_project  Frontend->add("page_dbtest", "dbtest", "Content")
C:\wamp\www\agiletoolkit\atk4\lib/ApiWeb.php    :332    sample_project  Frontend->layout_Content()
C:\wamp\www\agiletoolkit\atk4\lib/ApiFrontend.php   :33     sample_project  Frontend->addLayout("Content")
C:\wamp\www\agiletoolkit\atk4\lib/ApiWeb.php    :208    sample_project  Frontend->initLayout()
C:\wamp\www\agiletoolkit/index.php  :15     sample_project  Frontend->main()
```

Answer (score 2):

In your "C:\wamp\www\agiletoolkit" you will see a file called config-distrib.php. Copy paste it and rename it to config.php then change the dsn for connection.

DSN means Data Source Name.

You will find the following line in the config.php file.

```
$config['dsn']='mysql://root:root@localhost/project';
```

You can modify it to

```
$config['dsn']='mysql://root:@localhost/YOURDATABASENAME';
```

By default the database user is 'root' and password is '' and you are accessing the database on local host.

Also check, [this](http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/install/config) for more information.